1998 Ford 5.4 2V V8 E150 -- weird mismatch between intake manifold and block
I bought this 1998 Ford 5.4 2V V8 E150 van used and I noticed something wierd about how the intake manifold fits onto the... [not even sure what it's called... cylinder head?].
It looks like they don't even match.
Is this weird and/or suspicious? I put my finger on the hole to make sure there isn't a massive vacuum leak there and I didn't notice any suction.
Full View:

Closer:

